# Remove +1 on one side of a difference equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have a difference equation r ((i + 1) = ...

And I want the value of r(i) = ...

How can I remove the +1 on this side (how to I control for it on the other side) ? Basically I want to go back of one in the time.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Think of $r(i+1)$ as $r(\text{something}+1)$ and write
$$
r(i)=r((i-1)+1)
$$
Your new "something" is $(i-1)$. So you simply have to replace all occurences of $i$ (your old "something") in the RHS of your equation with $i-1$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, it was really helpful!